# Prove from axioms that $\vdash(P\implies \neg P)\implies(\neg\neg P \implies \neg P)$ in Hilbert's system

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Im supposed to prove
$$\vdash(P\implies \neg P)\implies(\neg\neg P \implies \neg P)$$
from following axioms:
$P\implies ( Q \implies P )$
$P\implies ( Q \implies R ) \implies (P\implies Q)\implies(P\implies R)$
$(\neg Q \implies \neg P)\implies(P\implies Q)$

I have also proven/is also known that:
$P\implies \neg \neg P$
$\neg\neg P\implies P$
$(P\implies \neg P)\implies \neg P$

Every attempt i've had has led to nowhere.. Any tips? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof of : $(P \to \lnot P) \vdash (\lnot \lnot P \to \lnot P).$

You have proved: $\vdash \lnot \lnot P \to P$. Thus:

1) $(P \to \lnot P)\vdash (\lnot \lnot P \to P)$

2) $(P \to \lnot P)\vdash \lnot \lnot P \to (P \to \lnot P)$ --- from (Ax.1) by *mp*

3) $\vdash [\lnot \lnot P \to (P \to \lnot P)] \to [(\lnot \lnot P \to P) \to (\lnot \lnot P \to \lnot P)]$--- (Ax.2)

Thus, from 1), 2) and 3) by *mp* twice, we get:

> 4) $(P \to \lnot P) \vdash (\lnot \lnot P \to \lnot P).$

Now, we can use the *Deduction Th* to conclude with:

> > 5) $\vdash (P \to \lnot P) \to  (\lnot \lnot P \to \lnot P)$.

---

In a similar way, we can avoid the last application of *DT* through a longer derivation based on (Ax.1), (Ax.2) only:

1) $\vdash \lnot \lnot P \to P$

2) $\vdash (P \to \lnot P ) \to (\lnot \lnot P \to P)$ --- from Ax.1 and 1) by *mp*

3) $\vdash (P \to \lnot P)\to [(\lnot \lnot P \to P) \to (P \to \lnot P)] \text {    (Ax.1)}$

4) $\vdash \{ (P \to \lnot P)\to [(\lnot \lnot P \to P) \to (P \to \lnot P)] \} \to \{ [(P \to \lnot P ) \to (\lnot \lnot P \to P)] \to [(P \to \lnot P) \to  (\lnot \lnot P \to \lnot P)] \} \text {    (Ax.2)}$

5) $\vdash [(P \to \lnot P ) \to (\lnot \lnot P \to P)] \to [(P \to \lnot P) \to  (\lnot \lnot P \to \lnot P)]$--- from 3) and 4) by *mp*

> 6) $\vdash (P \to \lnot P) \to  (\lnot \lnot P \to \lnot P)$--- from 2) and 5) by *mp*.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the deduction theorem, this is equivalent to showing $(P\Rightarrow \neg P)\vdash(\neg\neg P \Rightarrow \neg P)$, which is equivalent to $\{P\Rightarrow \neg P, \neg \neg P\}\vdash \neg P$. But this is straight forward:

1. $\neg\neg P$ (assumption)
2. $\neg\neg P \Rightarrow P$ (known)
3. $P$ (modus ponens on 1, 2)
4. $P \Rightarrow \neg P$ (assumption)
5. $\neg P$ (modus ponens on 3, 4)

Comment: Yes, didn't read about the deduction theory before doing.. Thanks

Comment: It is also possible without the deduction theorem, but significantly simpler with.